# Correctly declare callback method in Typescript for React Bootstrap DropdownItem

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

I have problems in declaring callback for `onClick` property in Dropdown.Item in Typescript. What  type `event` should be. I tried many versions without any luck. I know Dropdown.Item is rendered as an anchor and I want to do it correctly but couldn't find any way to declare type of `event` parameter. Please help me what type is `e` in my case. I'm trying `MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>` but typescript is complaining? What correct type should I use in this place? Of course everything is inside Function Component body etc... but I just extracted my problem here...

```
import React, { MouseEvent } from 'react';
import { Dropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';

const handleClick = ( e: MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement> ) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do something
  };

<Dropdown.Item href="#" role="button" onClick={ handleClick }>
  Item
</Dropdown.Item>
```

Typescript is complaining with this message:

```
Type '(e: MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: MouseEvent<ReplaceProps<BsPrefixComponentClass<"a", SafeAnchorProps>, BsPrefixProps<BsPrefixComponentClass<"a", SafeAnchorProps>> & DropdownItemProps>, MouseEvent>) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'e' and 'event' are incompatible.
```

Should I put all this crazy and long declaration in my callback declaration?

Comment: could you please include the codesandbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the definition of DropdownItem:

```
import React from 'react';
import SafeAnchor from './SafeAnchor';
import { BsPrefixPropsWithChildren, BsPrefixRefForwardingComponent, SelectCallback } from './helpers';
export interface DropdownItemProps extends BsPrefixPropsWithChildren {
    active?: boolean;
    disabled?: boolean;
    eventKey?: string;
    href?: string;
    onClick?: React.MouseEventHandler<this>;
    onSelect?: SelectCallback;
}
declare type DropdownItem = BsPrefixRefForwardingComponent<typeof SafeAnchor, DropdownItemProps>;
declare const DropdownItem: DropdownItem;
export default DropdownItem;
```

Using the definition of `React.MouseEventHandler`,

```
type MouseEventHandler<T = Element> = EventHandler<MouseEvent<T>>;
```

you arrive to:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Dropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { DropdownItemProps} from 'react-bootstrap/DropdownItem';

const handleClick = ( e: React.MouseEvent<DropdownItemProps>) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Do something
};
```

Comment: Thanks Lesiak. Polish Developers rules. Dzięki za wytłumaczenie jak krowie na rowie. Next time when I will have similar problems I will know how to handle it. Thanks!

Comment: @Lesiak, may I ask you to have a look at a react-bootstrap related question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64359611/reactjs-building-a-dynamic-horizontal-menu-with-dropdown-items-in-react-bootstr?noredirect=1#comment113807856_64359611 ?